# How to join multiple column with multiple other column(IN CROSS) in pandas and giving the array in resultant output?

Tags: python, pandas, join, concatenation, nan

So,here I want to take first 3 character(only alphabets/no) from column 1 and first 4 character(only alphabets/no) from column 2 and first 5 digits from column3a,column3b,column3c and column3d(whichever is present) and make an array of them like in desired output column given below.Condition is that I need to remove any kind of special characters like .,-,' etc and spaces and take only alphabetical and numerical characters.Also output should be NaN if any one of column1,2 or 3 is not present.(If both 1 and 2 present and 1 from column 3 is present then output should come.

```
Column1     Column2     Colum3a     Colum3b     Colum3c     Colum3d    S.NO DESIRED OUTPUT 
ABCDE       QWERTY      12345678    1223456     234567      1234589     1      
T.BCDF      W ERTY      567890      NaN         NaN         NaN         2
ERTYUMH     TY-IOPU     9845366     5672341     NaN         NaN         3
NaN         ERTYUI      1986788     NaN         NaN         NaN         4
SA--RTYUNK  QWPOIJH     NaN         NaN         34564557    NaN         5
WQER        QWER        NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         6
S'E         WERTER      12233412    NaN         NaN         5678908     7
```

Desired output column should be like:

```
DESIRED OUTPUT                                                        S.NO
["ABC|QWER|12345","ABC|QWER|12234","ABC|QWER|23456","ABC|QWER|12345"]   1
[TBC|WER|56789]                                                         2
["ERT|TYIO|98453","ERT|TYIO|56723"]                                     3
NaN                                                                     4
[SAR|QWPO|34564]                                                        5
NaN                                                                     6
["SE|WERT|12233","SE|WERT|56789"]                                       7
```

Please help me with this.I m concatenating using below codes but don't know how to make array with 3rd columns.

```
df1['column4'] = (df1['Column1'].str[:3] + '|' +
              df1['Column2'].str[:4] + '|' +
              df1['Column3'].astype(str).replace({'^nan$':None, '\.0$':''}, regex=True))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
#join first 3 and 4 values in columns
s = (df1['Column1'].str.replace('\W','').str[:3] + '|' + 
     df1['Column2'].str.replace('\W','').str[:4] + '|' )

#all another columns convert to strings, replace and add to s
f = lambda x: s + x.astype(str).replace({'^nan$':None, '\.0$':''}, regex=True).str[:5]
              
#for column filtered by name ('Colum3') add values to list
df1 = (df1.filter(like='Colum3').apply(f)
          .stack()
          .groupby(level=0)
          .agg(list)
          .to_frame('new')
          .join(df['S.NO'], how='right'))

print (df1)
                                                 new  S.NO
0  [ABC|QWER|12345, ABC|QWER|12234, ABC|QWER|2345...     1
1                                   [TBC|WERT|56789]     2
2                   [ERT|TYIO|98453, ERT|TYIO|56723]     3
3                                                NaN     4
4                                   [SAR|QWPO|34564]     5
5                                                NaN     6
6                     [SE|WERT|12233, SE|WERT|56789]     7
```

Comment: Hey @jezrael Thanks.But in new column,I need only alphabets like in 2nd row it should be [TBC|WERT|56789]  not [T.B|W ER|567890].Same in 3,5 and 7th rows as well. Also,Should take only 5 digits from column 3 a,b or c.

Comment: @Rakshita - Answer was edited.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution as a pipeline, that should work for an arbitrary number of columns. The only requirement is that one should be able to filter the column names (here using `Column` and `Colum3` as pattern), otherwise one need to build a list of those columns and use classical slicing:

```
(df.filter(like='Column').apply(lambda c: c.str.replace('\W', '', regex=True).str[:3])
   .join(df['S.NO DESIRED OUTPUT'])
   .assign(Column3=df.filter(like='Colum3').apply(list, axis=1))
   .explode('Column3').dropna(subset=['Column3'])
   .assign(Column3=lambda d: d['Column3'].astype(str).str[:5])
   .set_index('S.NO DESIRED OUTPUT')
   .astype(str)  
   .apply('|'.join, axis=1)
   .groupby(level=0).apply(list)
   .rename('DESIRED OUTPUT')
   .mask(df.filter(like='Column').isna().any(1))
   .reset_index()
)
```

output:

```
   S.NO DESIRED OUTPUT                                     DESIRED OUTPUT
0                    1  [ABC|QWE|12345, ABC|QWE|12234, ABC|QWE|23456, ...
1                    2                                    [TBC|WER|56789]
2                    3                                                NaN
3                    4                                    [nan|ERT|19867]
4                    5                                    [SAR|QWP|34564]
5                    7                                                NaN
```